# What's the best design pattern for abstracting away different backends?

Tags: design-patterns, backend, abstraction

Say you write an SVG library but want to provide support for multiple XML parsing libraries.

Or you have a game engine and want to support both OpenGL and DirectX.

Which design pattern best fulfills this abstraction of implementation?

Answer (score 2):

The [Strategy](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) pattern can be a good fit for this problem.

In your particular case, OpenGL and DirectX are two different strategies for rendering graphics. Alternately, JAXB and XmBeans can be two different strategies for parsing XML files.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an instance of the Adapter pattern, where you are requiring the XML parsing libraries to be adapted (by an intermediary class) such that they can interface with your system.

In practice you would define an interface that your system requires and any XML parsing library that will be used with the system has an adapter (wrapper) to mutate its interface to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a perfect use case for [Abstract Factory](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns#abstract-factory) pattern. Say you are on Linux system, you would create OpenGlFactory. On Windows box, you would create DirectXFactory. Using the factory interface you could then create the correct implementations of context, renderer, camera etc. whatever needed.

Check the link for an example.